# Problems passing byte array to JNI functions

Tags: java, android, string, java-native-interface, arrays

I'm using a JNI library that consists of a few C functions. In function1 I pass a byte array of size 128 like this:

```
static byte[] byteAry = new byte[128];
long ret1 = MyLibrary.function1(byteAry);
```

In function 2 I pass the byte array returned by function1 for further processing, as follows.

```
final int ret2 = MyLibrary.function2(byteAry);
```

In function2's C code, I get the length of the byteAry as follows:

```
jsize jsArruLen = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env,jDeviceListArr);
```

When I call function1 followed by function2, jsArruLen is 128, as it should be, since the bytearray is created as 128 bytes.

However, when I manually copy a string into byteary and then pass it to function2 by doing this:

```
final String mystring = "this is a string";
byteAry = mystring.getBytes();
```

jsArruLen is then only 16 bytes long, which is the length of mystring. How can I manually copy a string into byteAry without changing its size?

Thanks.

Comment: You create byteAry to be 128 bytes long. It's not necessarily filled all the way to the end. Probably only the indexes of 0 - 15 are filled in that 128 byte array (assumed that MyLibrary.function1 returns the string you manually use later on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that mystring.getBytes method returns a new byte array of the length of mystring, rather than copying mystring to the byte array. Hence, byteAry gets overwritten with a new byte array of the length of mystring. Doh. I overcame this by assigning mystring.getBytes to a temp byte array, then manually assigning each byte element of the temp array to byteary in a for loop. It works, but I'm wondering if there are methods to do this kind of copy?

Comment: FYI-The term "length of a string" is somewhat ambiguous. Logically, it is the number of characters (codepoints) in the string. In practice, it is often the number of equal-sized elements required to encode the string. In Unicode jargon, that's called the number of code units. You are incorrectly using the term as the number of bytes that `getBytes` returns. Since you are not specifying an encoding for `getBytes` Java is picking one for you. It's just coincidence if the number of bytes for a particular string in that encoding equals the number of characters in the string.